# Apache commons CSV-parse record with new line chars

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

How to parse a CSV record that contains new line characters within quotes as below

```
1, Test, "testing
testing
testing"
```

I'm currently using Apache CSV lib

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(new FileReader(file));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This happens because of the spaces around the delimiter. I works perfectly when the spaces are removed.

```
1,<SPACE>Test,<SPACE>"testing
testing
testing"
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Apache commons CSV is not a hard and fast requirement, yuou could use OpenCSV [CSVParser](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/), which has a constructor that takes the quote characters used in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(new FileReader(file_name));
```